# Using python to retrieve popular tweets

Tags: python, twitter

I am using Twython to get popular tweets. However I am only getting 15 per search function call. I already tried passing the count argument to the function to get more but it keeps returning 15.

Here is the code:

```
result = twitter.search(q='a', count=100, result_type='popular')

for item in result['statuses']:
    print(item['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

I also tried setting count='100' and count="100" but it is the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`result = twitter.search(q='a', count=100)`

Although this doesn't work with `result_type='popular'` and I haven't figured out why.

Also look into paginated search results here: [Twython search API with next_results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320197/twython-search-api-with-next-results)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me, with [twitter-node-client](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient) for future searchers. Looks like it's a [bug with the Twitter api](https://twittercommunity.com/t/problem-bug-get-search-tweets-count-parameter/10249/10)  .